# Bernoulli Process Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> Suppose on any given day you receive mail in your mailbox with common probability $p$. Assume that whether mail is put in the mailbox or not is independent from day to day.
>
> Find the probability your first received mail comes after a week.

So I let $Z$ be the event that the mail comes after a week, $X_i$ be the event where the first mail came on the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ day.
I rearranged the probability so that $$P(Z) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^7 P(X_i)$$
From here do I just use the geometric distribution for $\sum_{i=1}^7 P(X_i)$ for each $i$? The answer seems way too long so I had doubts here. Any tips would help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

$P(Z)$ = $P$(you have received your first mail after a week) $=$ $P$(you have not received any mail during first week) $=$ $(1-p)^7$